# `context` expression in Coq

Tags: coq, ltac

I am trying to understand 'context' **expression** (opposed to `context` **pattern**). In the manual it is described as:

> context ident [ expr ]
>
> ident must denote a context variable bound by a context pattern of a
>   match expression. This expression evaluates replaces the hole of the
>   value of ident by the value of expr.

Could somebody share an example illustrating the usage of this construct? I guess it must involve `match` using `context` pattern and then abovementioned form to use matched context.

Comment: I think it is a "hole". Anyway, this is what it says in the manual https://coq.inria.fr/refman/ltac.html#hevea_default856

Comment: heh ok ! sounds good..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that replaces `fst (a, _)` with `a` and `snd (_, b)` with `b`, but doesn't touch `fst` and `snd` applied to anything other than pair:

```
Ltac unfold_proj_pair :=
    repeat match goal with
           | [ |- context G[fst (?a, _)] ]
             => let G' := context G[a] in change G'
           | [ |- context G[snd (_, ?b)] ]
             => let G' := context G[b] in change G'
           end.
```

(Note that `cbn [fst snd]` is a simpler way to do this, and that also works under binders.)

Comment: Thanks! I think it would be great to include this or similar example in the manual.